# How do I delete the draft of the permissions I have requested on Facebook ? I haven't yet submitted the app for review

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

[image]
I need to delete these permissions first, I think I have made an error in asking for permissions.

Clicked on Edit button it takes  me to App Review. Tried using delete button on the permissions and features page that also didn't help. Can anyone help with this process.